# Reading an XML File using an XML object results in missing entries

Tags: json, xml, powershell

I’ve been given XML files to update, but when reading in the file using an XML object, multiple entries go missing.

The XML File (note two sectionGroup’s)

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="Albert" type="Male, Outlook=neutral" >
         <section name="Bobby" type="Male, Outlook=happy"/>
         <section name="Cathy" type="Female, Outlook=neutral"/>
         <section name="David" type="Male, History=Yes"/>
         <sectionGroup name="Mark" type="Male, Outlook=happy" >
              <section name="Matt" type="Male, Outlook=neutral"/>
         </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

The Script:

```
[XML] $xmlObj=Get-Content "C:\temp\infile.xml" -Raw

foreach ($elem in $xmlObj.configuration.configSections.sectionGroup.section)
    {
    Write-Host ("=> {0}='{1}'" -f $elem.name, $elem.type) 
    }
```

The output:

```
=>  Bobby='Male, Outlook=happy'
=>  Cathy='Female, Outlook=neutral'
=>  David='Male, History=Yes'
```

Note that is does not include the first name(Albert) or the two names in the second section (Mark, Matt).

I can't change the multiple XML files, so:

1. what needs to change in the code to see all entries?
2. When writing them back, are additional changes required as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use an XPath expression to select all `<section>` elements regardless of location:

```bsh
foreach($elem in $xmlObj.SelectNodes('//section')){
  # work with $elem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solve it.  Each is a different section, which needs to be specified.  This returns all 6

```
$xmlObj.configuration.configSections.sectionGroup  | % { Write-Host ("=> {0}='{1}'" -f $_.name, $_.type) }

$xmlObj.configuration.configSections.sectionGroup.section | % { Write-Host ("=> {0}='{1}'" -f $_.name, $_.type) }

$xmlObj.configuration.configSections.sectionGroup.sectionGroup | % { Write-Host ("=> {0}='{1}'" -f $_.name, $_.type) }

$xmlObj.configuration.configSections.sectionGroup.sectionGroup.section | % { Write-Host ("=> {0}='{1}'" -f $_.name, $_.type) }
```